# Alter column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is correct syntax for an `ALTER` statement to add a default value to an existing column?

I can add new column with no errors:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName ADD Record_Status varchar(20)
```

But If I try to alter existing column to apply default value by using the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName 
ALTER COLUMN Record_Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName 
ALTER Record_Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

I have get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Record_Status'.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you want this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName  
add constraint cnt_Record_Status Default '' for Record_Status
```

Based on some of your comments, I am going to guess that you might already have `null` values in your table which is causing the alter of the column to `not null` to fail.  If that is the case, then you should run an `UPDATE` first. Your script will be:

```
update tb_TableName
set Record_Status  = ''
where Record_Status is null

ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ALTER COLUMN Record_Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT DEF_Name DEFAULT '' FOR Record_Status
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7797/1)

Answer (score 6):

Try this one.

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ALTER COLUMN Record_Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT DEF_Name DEFAULT '' FOR Record_Status
```

Comment: Thank you. It would work. But there is no NOT NULL in Add Statment and I have to add it

Comment: Oh. I thought you also wanted to change your column to be Not Null.

Comment: Yes, I do, but "ALTER TABLE tb_TableName ALTER COLUMN Record_Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL " will not work

Answer (score 0):

To set a default value to a column, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_TableName
ALTER COLUMN Record_Status SET DEFAULT 'default value'
```