# Can I set a default integer value of an id that is auto incremented on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, default-value

I have the current table :

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Test_tuto

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| nom   | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

But when I try to add a default value on the AUTO_INCREMENT column

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE Test_tuto CHANGE id id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I get this error.

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'id'
```

I've found many articles about how to set a default value on columns but non of them mentions this case.

Comment: What does this mean? `AUTO_INCREMENT` means that it defaults to the next number, so how can it also default to 1?

Comment: You probably just want this: `ALTER TABLE Test_tuto CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as written isn't clear, because -- as Barmar points out -- the auto-increment *is* a default value for the column.

Perhaps you want to control where the auto increment column starts.  Of course, the value starts at "1", so the specific question is not relevant.  But you can set the initial value -- or next value -- by doing:

```
alter table test_tuto auto_increment = 1;
```

This is described in the documentation for [`create table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Comment: My lack of knowledge about the MySQL functionnalities and the various use cases made my question incomplete in precision.
Also I got confused about a use case where I'd love this particular id column to be set to 0 in other tables when used as a foreign key.
So my bad (This is my first day on MySQL course)

Answer (score 0):

Use This SQL Query Syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

your Problem solved.

Please Check This link to solve your problem.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294468/alter-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Where are you setting the default value?